# How to inform a selectfield element from response of Ext.Ajax.request?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, json, sencha-architect

I need to inform a selectfield sencha element from callback of Ext.Ajax.request({})

I have a this code, for example,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/express/EXPRESSVE00007_es.jsp',
            timeout: 90000,
            params: {
                evento  : action,
                cookie: document.cookie,
                NAME    : Ext.getCmp("txtName").getValue(),
                LAST    : Ext.getCmp("txtLast").getValue(),
                SEX : Ext.getCmp("txtSex").getValue()
            },
            success: function(r, o) {
                var response = r.responseText
                response = response.trim()
                response = response.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
                var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response)
                Ext.Msg.alert(jsonResponse)
            },
            failure: function() {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: "Failure",
                    msg: "Error, failed response",
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
                })
           }
})
```

and my selectfield,

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    id: 'selSex',
    name: 'select',
    label: '*Sex',
    placeHolder: 'Select...',
    displayField: 'desc',
    hiddenName: 'second-select',
    options: [
        {desc: '',  value: ''},
        {desc: '', value: ''}
    ]
}
```

In this case, I need to inform "desc" and "value" field from callback Ext.Ajax.request, but I don't know. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can inform the `selectfield` from an `Ext.Ajax.request` by updating it's `store`.

You could declare a store to *store* all the field values and then on response from the `request`, you can **shuffle** the data store to which `selectfield` is binded.

E.g

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    store: sampleStore,
    valueField:'value',
    displayField:'desc',
}
```

and update the store values on `Ext.Ajax.request`'s response like this,

```
Ext.StoreMgr.get('sampleStore').load();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do below

```
Test = Ext.regModel('Test', {
    fields: [{
        name: 'desc',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'value',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});

exStores = new Ext.data.Store({
     model: 'Test',
    autoLoad: false });
```

and select field

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    store: exStores,
    id: 'selSex',
    name: 'select',
    label: '*Sex',
    placeHolder: 'Select...',
    valueField:'value',
    displayField:'desc',
}
```

and ajax request

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            ...
            success: function(r, o) {
                var response = r.responseText
                response = response.trim()
                response = response.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
                var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response)
                exStores.loadData(jsonResponse, false);
                Ext.Msg.alert(jsonResponse)
            },
            ...
})
```

Hope this help.